# How to get className of an element in jsdom?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, jsdom

first time posting so sorry if I mess something up. Below is the code I have tried:

```
const domPreParse = new JSDOM(incident); //incident is the html fragment I want to parse
const dom = domPreParse.window.document;

const cNameHome = dom.querySelector('[data-type="home-icon"], svg').className;
```

So `cNameHome` returns an object with only the first class name. There are multiple class name on the element (e.g. `class="class1 class2"`). How can I return all the classes in a space separated string preferably.

And this is the code I'm trying to parse:

```
<div class="sco" data-type="middle">
    <div class="clear">
        <span class="inc" data-type="home-icon"></span>
        <span class="score" data-type="score">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="inc" data-type="away-icon">
            <svg class="inc yellowcard"><use xlink:href="#icon-yellowcard"></use></svg>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you certain that none of the other classes are added dynamically by a script or such?

Comment: I am sure. I am passing in a piece of HTML that I print and I can see multiple classes on the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my CSS selectors. I should have used `[data-type="home-icon"] > svg`.